# Error while 'building APK'. "Make Project" does execute fine without any error though

Tags: android-studio, runtime-error, dagger-2

I am new to Android development and am getting following error when building the APK. I have no idea about the cause. 
I have been debugging this app many a times and was working fine. Just after few changes I am getting following errors. Could someone please help me with this?

`Make Project` though does execute fine without any error.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.\nThis is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.\nIf you are using the \u0027java\u0027 gradle plugin in a library submodule add \ntargetCompatibility \u003d \u00271.7\u0027\nsourceCompatibility \u003d \u00271.7\u0027\nto that submodule\u0027s build.gradle file.","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\njava.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:775)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:741)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:88)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1683)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:695)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:592)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:321)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:292)\n\tat com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:54)\n\tat com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexInProcess$0(DexByteCodeConverter.java:173)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\nCaused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:476)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:787)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1600(Main.java:88)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1722)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:773)\n\t... 16 more\n","tool":"Dex"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
//    dataBinding {
//        enabled = true
//    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dbpa"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.github.frankiesardo:auto-parcel:0.3.1'
    apt     'com.github.frankiesardo:auto-parcel-processor:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

}
```

Comment: Which java version are you using? Looks like the libraries you have have been compiled with java 8.

Comment: Yes its 8. (java version "1.8.0_121")

Comment: Care to post your build.gradle file?

Comment: Posted in the question.

Comment: I could reproduce the error even in new project after including
`
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'

Comment: @DineshKumar thanks for the clue!!

Answer (score 0):

Using following solved the issue:

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
```

My "Day 1" with dagger!! ;-)